# How do you remove Safari 7.0.4 on Mac OS X 10.7.5

Tags: macos, safari

How do you remove Safari 7.0.4 on Mac OS X 10.7.5?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is it causing some sort of problem? What happens when you pull Safari.app to the trash?

Comment: Do you want to have no Safari at all, or a different version? If the latter, which version do you want?

Answer (score 1):

If you just wanted to get the old version back, browse [this official list](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#safari) of available Safari and pick the version you need. The currently installed version can be deleted by dragging it into Trash (requires admin rights).